# MATLAB Parse Data file

Tags: matlab, file, parsing

I have a text file that contains many lines of header and overhead information. Then, following that, there are repetitive blocks of data that I am interested in capturing. However, the first block is a bit different then the ones that follow it. The file structure is as follows:

```
**Header and overhead:**
...
...
...
SPD -> PX: SS3Data[07]: Recv Data
Sync:     0xXXXXXXXX
Chan:     N
ID:       N
Seq:      N
SS:       N
Words:    N
Time:     0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PX: SS3Data[07]: Recv Data
Sync:     0xXXXXXXXX
Chan:     N
ID:       N
Seq:      N
SS:       N
Words:    N
Time:     0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PX: SS3Data[07]: Recv Data
Sync:     0xXXXXXXXX
Chan:     N
ID:       N
Seq:      N
SS:       N
Words:    N
Time:     0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I'd like to be able to capture the data in the said Blocks and store them in a structure such as the following:

```
S.Block1.Sync
S.Block1.Chan
S.Block1.Chan
S.Block1.ID
S.Block1.Seq
S.Block1.SS
S.Block1.Words
S.Block1.Time
S.Block1.Data
.
.
.
S.BlockN.Sync
S.BlockN.Chan
S.BlockN.Chan
S.BlockN.ID
S.BlockN.Seq
S.BlockN.SS
S.BlockN.Words
S.BlockN.Time
S.BlockN.Data
```

The X's following the Time field are HEX characters. There is 64 characters in the first line, and 32 in the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach for this problem depends on the size of your files. If you can read it in all at once, I would suggest the following approach using textscan()

```
% read file => stored in "data.txt"
fID = fopen(fullfile(cd, 'data.txt'), 'r');
tmp = textscan(fID, '%s');
fclose(fID);
lines = tmp{1};

% find rows with data. You might want to add some additional checks, or
% check whether the labels are indeed always in this order
chan_row = find(strcmpi(lines, 'Chan:'))+1; % could add a check here that the distance between the rows is all the same

% save in a table
tbl = table();
tbl.Chan = lines(chan_row);
tbl.ID = lines(chan_row+2);
tbl.Seq = lines(chan_row+4);
tbl.SS = lines(chan_row+6);
tbl.Words = lines(chan_row+8);
tbl.Time = lines(chan_row+10);
tbl.Data = lines(chan_row+12);
```

Note that I store the results in a table. This is likely much easier to process than your struct with the id number in the name. Per field, you might want to do some additional transformations, such as converting particular fields to categoricals.

If that is not feasible because the file is very large, you could try fopen() in combination with fgetl() to read in line-by-line instead.

Comment: This worked very well for the most part. I modified the Data portion such that:
temp_DataLine1 = lines(chan_row+11); and temp_DataLine2 = lines(chan_row+12);. Then, I strcat the two: tbl.Data = strcat(temp_DataLine1,temp_DataLine2).

Answer (score 0):

If this is only a one time data capture rather than something that's actually part of your code, just ctrl-c the data in notepad, then in Matlab click on your variable workspace and ctrl-v. It should bring up a window that will let you import that data easily enough